# How to keep open a materialize datepicker on blur?

Tags: html, jquery, css, datepicker, materialize

**Problem:**
I am using upgraded materialize date picker(version 1.0.0) and I want my date-picker calendar to remain open on clicking outside the calendar. Thanks in Advance.

**What I have tried:**
Firstly, I have tried.

`picker.set('select', new Date());`

But it also closes the date picker because, if the date is selected, then it is not closing the date picker on clicking the header of the modal, but if we are not initializing the date picker then it closes the date picker on clicking the modal's header.

Answer (score 0):

If the date picker use model than use the following code.

```
$('.modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```